# I config docker bridge but now the network in container can't work will

Tags: docker

I want to specify the docker container's IP address range to the host's, which has also been realized followed [this tutor](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#bridge-building), WHILE it is still inaccessible to the global network. Of course I have checked the IP specified through `ifconfig`.

THEN, could you give me some suggestion or solution to this problem?

```
root@ubuntu:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.000000000000   no      
root@ubuntu:~# brctl addbr bridge0
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr add 10.0.3.1/24 dev bridge0
root@ubuntu:~# ip link set dev bridge0 up
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr show bridge0
4: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 0e:3a:46:ac:fe:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.1/24 scope global bridge0
    inet6 fe80::c3a:46ff:feac:fe57/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@ubuntu:~# echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-b=bridge0"' >> /etc/default/docker 
root@ubuntu:~# service docker restart
docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 3166
```

Then, I run ubuntu:14.04 container

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
root@630046b814dc:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:00:03:02  
          inet addr:10.0.3.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:aff:fe00:302/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:238 (238.0 B)  TX bytes:328 (328.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

When I try ping host IP

```
root@630046b814dc:/# ping 10.0.3.87
PING 10.0.3.87 (10.0.3.87) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.3.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.3.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.3.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```